# plot2d() hangs infinitely, single function call ok

Tags: maxima

I'm certain, that I'm violating some sacred maxima rule.
My function executes fine, when I'm running it with a single argument.
But when trying to plot the results, maxima hangs infinitely.
Any help would be appreciated...

```
define_variable(IS1, 1e-12, real);
define_variable(IS2, 1.2e-12, real);
define_variable(N1, 1.5, real);
define_variable(N2, 1.8, real);
define_variable(VT, 0.025, real);
define_variable(R, 1.0e4, real);
define_variable(VE, 1.0, real);
define_variable(EPS, 1.0e-3, real);
ID1(VD):=IS1*(exp(VD/(N1*VT))-1);
ID2(VD):=IS2*(exp(VD/(N2*VT))-1);

F(V1, V2):=[(VE-V1)/R - ID1(V1-V2), ID1(V1-V2)-ID2(V2)];
define(F1(V1, V2), jacobian(F(V1, V2), [V1, V2]));
define(newton33(V1, V2), [V1, V2] - invert_by_lu(F1(V1, V2)).F(V1, V2));
define(newton(V1, V2), block([val : newton33(V1, V2)], [val[1][1], val[2][1]]));
newton2(V1, V2, n):=block([val : newton(V1, V2)], if (((val[1]-V1)**2 + (val[2]-V2)**2) < (EPS*EPS)) then [val, n*1.0] else newton2(val[1], val[2], n+1));
newton3(x1):=newton2(x1, 0.0, 0)[2];
plot2d(newton3(x), [x, -1.0, 1.0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

changing the last line from
    plot2d(newton3(x), [x, -1.0, 1.0]);
to
    plot2d(newton3, [x, -1.0, 1.0]);
fixes this problem...

Comment: When Maxima sees `plot2d(newton3(x), ...)`, it tries to evaluate `newton3(x)` before calling `plot2d`. But `newton3` doesn't evaluate to a number when its argument is not a number. In order to make plotting work, you need to postpone evaluation of `newton3`. Writing `plot2d(newton3, ...)` does that. I think `plot2d('(newton3(x)), ...)` (i.e. prevent evaluation via quoting) will do as well.